# Create a Regex pattern from a string

Tags: c#, regex, matching

Im trying to create a regex pattern form any given string in C#, so if user enters 6 digits, it would create regex matching 6 digits, but Im not sure if there is any function in C# to achieve this.

I would be thankful if you help me with this one.

Comment: Have you tried anything as a concept ? so that we could help you better

Comment: There would just be too many variables. How would you differentiate between "I want three consecutive digits, so '999'" and "I want the string literal '999', so '999'"? There are questions like that, and any scripting language of that nature would have to make some pretty wild estimates about what the user was going for.

Answer (score 4):

If you want a regex that matches exactly the string of digits the user entered, then you can use

```
var Regex = new Regex(Regex.Escape(enteredString));
```

However, if you want to detect that the user entered 6 digits, and then generate a regex that matches any other sequence of 6 digits, then your problem is poorly defined. For example, if the user supplies the string "ABCD", would you want to create a regex that matches 4 letters? 4 uppercase letters? 4 hexadecimal digits? You can see how "guessing the pattern" would be problematic.